# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk EC-2 automatically created a backup file for my Laravel production project

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, centos, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to deploy my Laravel project and deployed the codes this early year. The weird thing is, when I check some of the files were automatically generated as a backup file using the codes from January 2020 even though we've updated the codes recently.

Below is the picture of the files generated : [image]

This was obviously not manually created as I have checked with the programmers and the files were created at 1 am.

I would like to know what causes this to happen and how do I prevent it from happening cause the generated files will be using the old codes and break the system.

Comment: Its not something that EB does by itself. Could be larval specific, or you have something in .ebextentations that makes the backups?

Comment: @Marcin thanks for the response. I've checked the .ebextensions we don't have anything that generate the backups.